# Accessing Scrollbar control on excel sheet using C#

Tags: c#, excel, controls, scrollbar, office-interop

I want to add an Scrollbar control to my excel sheet using [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23). I don't want to use the `Windows.Forms.Scrollbar` but the one, Excel provides.

Adding the control is no problem - my problem is to access the created control to define the minimum, maximum and the cell-reference. Here is my code:

```
    public static void AddScrollBar(Ex.Worksheet ExSH, int StartCellRow, int StartCellColumn, int EndCellRow, int EndCellColumn, int ReferenceRow, int ReferenceColumn, int MaxValue, int MinValue = 0, int CurrentValue = 0)
    {
        int Left, Top, Right, Bottom;
        if(StartCellRow > EndCellRow || StartCellColumn > EndCellColumn) { throw new System.Exception("EROR: Please check Start- and Endcell reference or flip it!"); }

        Left = (int)(ExSH.Cells[StartCellRow, StartCellColumn] as Ex.Range).Left;
        Top = (int)(ExSH.Cells[StartCellRow, StartCellColumn] as Ex.Range).Top;
        Right = (int)((ExSH.Cells[EndCellRow, EndCellColumn] as Ex.Range).Left + (ExSH.Cells[EndCellRow, EndCellColumn] as Ex.Range).Width);
        Bottom = (int)((ExSH.Cells[EndCellRow, EndCellColumn] as Ex.Range).Top + (ExSH.Cells[EndCellRow, EndCellColumn] as Ex.Range).Height);

        Ex.ControlFormat SB = ExSH.Shapes.AddFormControl(Ex.XlFormControl.xlScrollBar, Left, Top, Right - Left, Bottom - Top) as Ex.ControlFormat;
        SB.Value = CurrentValue; /*ERROR: Object reference not set to an instance of an object*/
        SB.Min = MinValue;
        SB.Max = MaxValue;
        SB.LinkedCell = (ExSH.Cells[ReferenceRow, ReferenceColumn] as Ex.Range).ToString();
    }
```

The error occurs in Line 12 (SB.Value = ...)
When I comment the lines `SB.Value = ...` to `SB.LindedCell = ...`, the code runs well. Opening the created Excel Workbook and selecting the depending Worksheet, I can find the created scrollbar where it should be.
When I break after the creation of the scrollbar, SB is .

Can anybody help me? I'm not so skilled in advances [office-interop](/questions/tagged/office-interop) stuff.

Thank you in advance,
Jan

Answer (score 2):

Ah, I found it. SB is a Ex.Shape. And then, you can access the parameter by SB.ControlFormat.Min, Max, Value etc.

Here is the working code:

```
    public static void AddScrollBar(Ex.Worksheet ExSH, int StartCellRow, int StartCellColumn, int EndCellRow, int EndCellColumn, int ReferenceRow, int ReferenceColumn)
    {
        int Left, Top, Right, Bottom;
        if(StartCellRow > EndCellRow || StartCellColumn > EndCellColumn) { throw new System.Exception("EROR: Please check Start- and Endcell reference or flip it!"); }

        Left = (int)(ExSH.Cells[StartCellRow, StartCellColumn] as Ex.Range).Left;
        Top = (int)(ExSH.Cells[StartCellRow, StartCellColumn] as Ex.Range).Top;
        Right = (int)((ExSH.Cells[EndCellRow, EndCellColumn] as Ex.Range).Left + (ExSH.Cells[EndCellRow, EndCellColumn] as Ex.Range).Width);
        Bottom = (int)((ExSH.Cells[EndCellRow, EndCellColumn] as Ex.Range).Top + (ExSH.Cells[EndCellRow, EndCellColumn] as Ex.Range).Height);

        Ex.Shape SB = ExSH.Shapes.AddFormControl(Ex.XlFormControl.xlScrollBar, Left, Top, Right - Left, Bottom - Top);
        SB.ControlFormat.Value = CurrentValue;
        SB.ControlFormat.Min = MinValue;
        SB.ControlFormat.Max = MaxValue;
        SB.ControlFormat.LinkedCell = "A" + ReferenceRow.ToString();
    }
```